# Awesomium sdk download

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, awesomium

Is there a way to download Awesomium latest sdk or for visual studio 2015 since their website is down?
I need it for a project I found for visual basic which Awesomium core and some functions are required..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Note that a standard close reason is _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam._  This is basically asking us to find an off-site resource.

Comment: Try looking under http://http://wiki.awesomium.net/ and follow links.  You may manage to find code to download (but the http://www.awesomium.com/download link leads to the "We're building something awesome" page with the option to sign up for emails.  I note that the GitHub pages backing the site appear to have been last updated in 2016, which (I my estimation) bodes ill for the product — it's a long time not to be available.

Comment: You could try writing an email to the address specified on the website. But I would strongly recommend to refactor your project and use an alternative like [CefGlue](https://bitbucket.org/xilium/xilium.cefglue/overview), [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) or [ChromiumFX](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumfx/chromiumfx) instead.

Comment: @PspSetProcessPpmPolicy I would suggest [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef). The libraries I mentioned are basically just wrappers for CEF.

Comment: @PspSetProcessPpmPolicy I am not a legal person so I will not give any explicit legal advice. According to their web-site it is using a BSD-license. You may want to consult the [Wikipedia article about BSD-licences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).

Comment: i have the install somewhere i believe. if youre still interested, reply to this.

Answer (score 12):

Version 1.7.5 of the SDK is currently downloadable from the Wayback Machine:

- [For Windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20170402001925/http://www.awesomium.com/downloads/awesomium_1_7_5_1_sdk_win.exe)
- [For Mac](https://web.archive.org/web/20151018175051/http://www.awesomium.com/downloads/awesomium_1_7_5_sdk_mac.dmg)

Comment: Thank you, I was really looking for a downloadable file for so long.

Answer (score 2):

While Awesomium is not maintained any longer a good alternative is [CEF](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/overview). It is a little more difficult to use to use but the documentation is quite extensive so you should get started easily. Questions get answered quite quickly on the [official CEF forum](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/) according to my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Awesomium Sdk Version 1.6.6 for Win

http://markdownpad.com/download/awesomium_v1.6.6_sdk_win.exe